# A sufficient condition for unsatisfiability

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, reductions

Let $\varphi = \bigwedge C_k$, in which $C_k$ is a clause in *X3SAT* (exactly-one *3SAT* or one-in-three *3SAT*). That is, $C_k = (l_i \odot l_j \odot l_u)$ such that $l_i \in \{x_i, \overline{x}_i\}$ for any $i$. Then, $C_k$ is true iff exactly one of $\{l_i, l_j, l_u\}$ is true. Hence, if $C_k$ is true, then $[l_i \Rightarrow (\overline{l}_j \wedge \overline{l}_u)] \wedge [l_j \Rightarrow (\overline{l}_i \wedge \overline{l}_u)] \wedge [l_u \Rightarrow (\overline{l}_i \wedge \overline{l}_j)]$ is satisfiable. Thus, $\phi_k = (\overline{l}_i \vee \overline{l}_j) \wedge (\overline{l}_i \vee \overline{l}_u) \wedge (\overline{l}_j \vee \overline{l}_u)$. Let $\varphi' = \bigwedge \phi_k$, which is in *2SAT*. If $\varphi'$ is unsatisfiable, then $\varphi$ is unsatisfiable. Is this result significant?

For example, consider $\varphi = (x_1 \odot \overline{x}_2 \odot x_3) \wedge (\overline{x}_1 \odot \overline{x}_2 \odot x_4) \wedge (x_2 \odot \overline{x}_3 \odot x_4)$. Then, $\varphi' = (\overline{x}_1 \vee x_2) \wedge (\overline{x}_1 \vee \overline{x}_3) \wedge (x_2 \vee \overline{x}_3) \wedge  (x_1 \vee x_2) \wedge (x_1 \vee \overline{x}_4) \wedge (x_2 \vee \overline{x}_4) \wedge (\overline{x}_2 \vee x_3) \wedge (\overline{x}_2 \vee \overline{x}_4) \wedge (x_3 \vee \overline{x}_4)$

Answer (score 0):

No.  It is not significant.  $\varphi'$ is a much weaker condition.  $\varphi'$ allows each clause to have either 0 or 1 satisfied literals.  It's much easier to satisfy that restriction.  I don't expect that this will be useful in practice, and it has no value for proving new theoretical results that I can see.

If the $x_i$'s are all variables (i.e., positive literals), then $\varphi'$ is always satisfiable (consider the assignment that assigns every $x_i$ to False), so the result is trivial.

Comment: I revised the question.